# Chart under a Map - Fusion Tables

Tags: google-maps, charts, google-api, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to make in map in which the user can click on a city as see a graph under the same map. All this with Fusion Tables can be something like this: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/map_chart

I want to visualize, under the map a graph [like this one](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=GVIZ&t=BAR&gco_isStacked=false&gco_booleanRole=certainty&gco_hAxis=%7B%22useFormatFromData%22%3atrue,%20%22viewWindow%22%3a%7B%22max%22%3anull,%20%22min%22%3anull%7D,%20%22minValue%22%3anull,%20%22maxValue%22%3anull,%20%22title%22%3a%22euros%22%7D&gco_vAxes=%5B%7B%22useFormatFromData%22%3atrue,%20%22minValue%22%3anull,%20%22maxValue%22%3anull,%20%22viewWindow%22%3anull,%20%22viewWindowMode%22%3anull,%20%22textStyle%22%3a%7B%22color%22%3a%22none%22,%20%22fontSize%22:12%7D%7D,%7B%22useFormatFromData%22%3atrue%7D%5D&gco_legend=top&gco_title=Klaus%20Wowereit%20%28Berl%C3%ADn%29&containerId=gviz_canvas&q=select%20col1,%20col5,%20col8%20from%201EzM51MWfkGbM-AnSHkrIH05ieB2uxo6yHeDyYGI%20where%20col0%20=%20%27Alemania%27&qrs=%20and%20col1%20%3E=%20&qre=%20and%20col1%20%3C=%20&qe=%20limit%201&width=500&height=300).

Any suggestions on how to visualize it under the graph? I thought it was easy - but it is not.

Thanks!